# How to force MPMoviePlayerViewController to fullscreen?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

Can anybody tell me how to force MPMoviePlayerViewController to Play in fullscreen as soon as it starts playing a video. I have tried setFullScreen:animated: function but it is not working. So can anybody help me out from this? Thanks in advance.

Also I'm using video file from my application bundle only.

Comment: what output you're having currently?

Comment: It is playing but not in full screen.

Comment: if you could put a screen shot of your output that would be much better to understand

Comment: I had tried myself and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appVid"
                                                                          ofType:@"mp4"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
moviePlayer.view.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].bounds;
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Ashwani Sharma Use This

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Robot" withExtension:@"m4v"];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
```

And Than +1

Comment: This not that I want...I had tried myself and it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Actually What you want ?

Comment: I think you mean "And then +1"